# auto login remote site inner in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, autologin

I have an existing remote site which has Authentication to access, now I want to combine this site in my own site using iframe. Is there any solution which can help to auto login remote site when load the iframe?

```
<iframe src="http://remote.com/list"></iframe>
```

If want to access http://remote.com/list, login require and only post username/password works. How to auto login when iframe loaded?

Here are some restriction

- login only works with post method
- iframe / javascript  has cross domain issue
- no login API provide
- no other modification can do in remote site

Answer (score 26):

Everything's possible. However the solution below is very insecure due to disclosure of access details to the remote page.

```
<form id="login" target="frame" method="post" action="http://remote.com/login">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="pass" />
</form>

<iframe id="frame" name="frame"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
    document.getElementById('login').submit();

    // once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        if (iframe.src != "http://remote.com/list") {
            iframe.src = "http://remote.com/list";
        }
    }
</script>
```

The values of `username` and `password` inputs are readable on the client side.

Comment: can we use it server side to hide the credential.

Comment: seems like the best answer for the problem; i suggest you accept this

Comment: Can you explain more of the security risks of this implementation?

Answer (score 11):

If you own the other site then you can try authentication through some token.

Pass an authorized token to url in the iframe.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my implementation for doing this. This does not solve the cross-domain issue though. For the cross-domain issue, you can try using jQuery's [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) method (I haven't tried combining jQuery with this solution yet).

```
<iframe id="MyIFrame" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframeURL = 'http://mysite.com/path/applicationPage.aspx';
    var iframeID = 'MyIFrame';

    function loadIframe(){
        //pre-authenticate
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST",this.iframeURL, false, "username", "password"); //use POST to safely send combination
        req.send(null); //here you can pass extra parameters through

        //setiFrame's SRC attribute
        var iFrameWin = document.getElementById(this.iframeID);
        iFrameWin.src = this.iframeURL + "?extraParameters=true";
    }

    //onload, call loadIframe() function
    loadIframe();   
</script>
```

Comment: Is this really safe? Having the username and password hard coded in the js file that can be downloaded by the client?

Comment: This was the easiest and fastest way for me to load an <iframe> with authentication in a *.hta.

Answer (score 5):

Can't be done. Simple as that. The cross domain restrictions are in place quite specifically to stop you from being able to do something like that.

The only exception is if you are the owner of the remote site and fully control the server so you can add CORS headers to allow your own external services permission to access it.

Comment: I think you are incorrect , The cross domain protection  can be bypassed by simply turning off the flag in the chrome browser  , It's not the server that tells you you have a cross domain issue , It's always the browser !!  so if you are using this for your self you can simply turn cross domain prompt off in chrome ..  easy

Comment: You can turn it off for you, but any developer that instructs their users to disable the build in security measures to use their site should be banned from the internet.

Comment: @PhonicUK can it be done if you are the owner of that domain where the source of the page that iframe is trying to get is, and set the cors to allow origin from the domain where the iframe is placed?