# How to pass credentials to iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, iframe

I am working on Kibana, and to display my kibana's dashboard, I am using iframe in HTML, and my kibana dashboard has authentication [using ReadOnlyRest Plug-in].

To pass credentials I used the below format.

*http://user1:user1@myhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/xyz_dashboard*.

Now if I want the dynamic credentials value in place of `"user1:user1"` I want to use JavaScript or Ajax or Angularjs using rest.

And I am seriously blank and searched a lot, but got nothing which I can understand.

Please assist me.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="myFrame" width="600" height="300"></iframe> 

<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute in the iframe.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "http://user1:user1@localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/xyz_dashboard";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>

I have tried only this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878947/auto-login-remote-site-inner-in-iframe.

Found this link, so somewhere i got idea that it can be done using JavaScript. i have no idea and very less time to finish this work

Comment: update this code in your question? yeah this could be done throug javascript

Comment: I have not written any code just my work is to give the HTML file which contains Iframe with credentials.

As i do not know JavaScript i need time to learn but there is no time. :'(

Comment: Akhilesh Singh, Any Links which can help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and make a variable in your js code.Look at the window object, you might be abble to get the user from there. For ex :`

```
<script> 
  function myFunction() {
  var user = getCurrentUser(); // where getCurrentUser is a way to get the user
  var source =  user + "@localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/…;;";
  document.getElementById("myFrame").src = source;
} 
</script>`
```

Comment: Hi R.Czq,

I will give a try and let you know.

Comment: **Hi,**


If i send the credentials as the you mentioned in script, will the credential be visible?

Comment: Hi, R.Czq i finally finished my requirement,

 thank you for guiding me.