# iFrame Auto-Login to External Site?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to automatically log in to an external site via iFrame. I do not have access to make changes to the site within the iFrame. Security concerns are out of scope for this project.

Functionally it needs to work like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878947/auto-login-remote-site-inner-in-iframe). Here is the code inspired by that link:

HTML

```
<form id="login" target="frame" method="post" action="foo.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="username" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="password123" />
</form>

<button id="send">Submit</button>

<div>
    <iframe id="frame" name="frame" src="https://foo.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#send').click(function () {
    document.getElementById('login').submit();
});
```

Running this code gives an error, stating that a required parameter was missing from the url. Manually logging in gives no error. I have no console errors.

Comment: The full error would be more useful here.