# Can i post data(username and password) to another website from my .NET web application to get login?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working in .NET web based application, what i wanted to do is that i want to pass a username and password from my .NET web app to another python based web application (http://172.20.47.21:8069/web/login) and post the data to that server to get login into that account. Is is possible with some .NET code or Javascript code ? If it is then how ? I don't want to open a login page of that python web app. I want to post that form from my .NET app and after successful authentication i should navigate to the main Dashboard page of python app.

Comment: yes haider it's posible, what you have to check is that another site's method which will consume your input and return user data for that login, if you can find that method, you just have to call it, you can try with C-sharp code or java script ajax.

Comment: yes brother, that's the issue, i cannot find the method for login.

Comment: We won't be able to find it :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at iframes. You could load a webpage and fill out the login details and submit the form. Once logged in, you can display the page to your user.

Comment: Take a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/16833828/3645638

Comment: @HaiderMustafa if there is no method available, then you have to create one in python web, like #taha answered, then call that method and validate your user. it's a pretty simple, don't think big, go step by step..

Comment: ok, gonna try that

Answer (score 0):

Off course you can do this in .Net ,one method is by using web api ,
all you need to do is to create web api inside python application on which data will be posted from .net application and call that api method from .net like this method send user token and user name to api and get response as object of UsersTB.
You can read [here](https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq) how to create web api in python.

```
 private UsersTB getuserDateByUserNameApi(string username, int userTypeId, string token)
    {
   string baseUri ="Url address of python application";
       try
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);//baseUri

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                //httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
                var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format("api/client/getuserDateByUsername/{0}/{1}/{2}", username, userTypeId, WebSiteID)).Result;

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersTB>(response.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            return null;
        }

    }  //api get
```

Comment: How will it be possible, because I am not a python specialist , that's why i wanted to remain at .NET side .

Comment: You must write some code on python side to handle this because when you post data some where and wait for response ,that application must then reply.