# Click inside a iframe (cross-site) possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load a page, `www.example2.com/page.html`, inside an iframe located at `www.mysiteexample.com`.When the page is loaded I need to simulate a click inside the iframe, searching by element id.

Is it possible to bypass cross-site scripting?

This is my script, that doesn't work:

```
function onMyFrameLoad() {
  $("#iframe").contents().find("#btn-to-push").click();
};
```

```html
<iframe id='iframe' src="http://www.example2.com/page.html" onload="onMyFrameLoad(this)"></iframe>
```

Comment: No this is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: You should *never* need to bypass XSS securities.

Comment: If you own both of those, you can look into `window.postMessage()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: What is the end result that you're looking to accomplish? *Why* do you need to push the button in the iframe? What does it do?

Comment: @wahwahwah i need to do an automation from my webapp: actually it login to site2 with curl request to access to a private page based on username and password already saved on site1... on this private page then I need to simulate a click to execute a script. this script do some magic....then from site1 I can do another curl to get updated results to save to site1 db

Comment: does website2 expose an API? This is the job for that kind of architecture. The kind of workaround you are trying to put in place is not a good idea at all

Comment: @LelioFaieta no, it is an "abandoned" website. but working with data we need

Comment: Take a look at [this post "auto login site inner in iframe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878947/auto-login-remote-site-inner-in-iframe)

Comment: @wahwahwah i already done my own login with curl and it works. my needs is to "click" using jquery a button inside iframe (external website)